# React using i18next in static file

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux-toolkit, i18next

I'm using i18next and redux-toolkit in my mobile project,

I got and menu-list static data, it simply like this.

```
const menuListData = [
 {
      id: 1,
      titleT: 'title1',          
  },
  {
      id: 2,
      titleT: 'title2',   
  },  ];
 export default menuListData;
```

just id and title, i got language store, lang files like this

```
export default en = { // also got for another lang
    translation: { 
      "title1": 'Title 1', 
      "title2": 'Title 2', 
    }
  }
```

I just want to use i18n translations in static file like this, but it gives error

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import React from "react";

const MenuList = (props) => {
    const i18n = useSelector((state) => state.langStore.i18n);
}
const titleTranslate = (metin) => {
    const i18n = useSelector((state) => state.langStore.i18n);
    return i18n.t(metin);
}
const menuListData = [
    {
        id: 1,
        titleT: i18n.t('title2'),
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        titleT: i18n.t('title2'),
    },
];
export default menuListData;
```

How can i make it, thank you

I made just and export file

```
const getMenuListData = (t) => [  
  {
    id: 1,
    titleT: t('title1'), 
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    titleT: t('title2'),  
  },    
];

export const data = getMenuListData;
```

Then the component I call it , I gave it to i18n.t prop like tihs

```
 import { data } from "./menuListData";
 //in function
  const menuData = data(i18n.t);
```

Then it works, thanks all

Comment: Redux doesn't really work with functions and classes as state values. I think you should look at alternatives that don't involve mixing redux with i18n. You're probably better off just using `React.Context` for your i18n piece of work.

Comment: Yeah you may be true but I also need to get experienced in redux :)

Comment: I mean it though, classes and functions as redux values just don't work in redux.

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to use i18n translations in static file like this, but it gives error

You are getting errors because there's no `i18n.t` function in the global scope of the file.

You could convert the `menuListData` variable into a function e.g. `getMenuListData` and pass the translate function into it as an *argument*.

```
const getMenuListData = (t) => [
    {
        id: 1,
        titleT: t('title2'),
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        titleT: t('title2'),
    },
];
```

Then, just call it inside e.g. `MenuList` component:

```
const MenuList = (props) => {
   const i18n = useSelector((state) => state.langStore.i18n);
   
   const data = getMenulistData(i18n.t);
}
```

Comment: then how can return just the data

Comment: i gotta use this just like json object in another component

Comment: I got this it, commented

Answer (score 0):

```
const getMenuListData = (t) => [  
  {
    id: 1,
    titleT: t('title1'), 
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    titleT: t('title2'),  
  },    
];

export const data = getMenuListData;
```

Then the component I call it , I gave it to i18n.t prop like tihs

```
 import { data } from "./menuListData";
 //in function
  const menuData = data(i18n.t);
```